# Qt "BoundsChecker"? Any recommendation for tool?

Tags: qt

Any good recommended tool for memory testing Qt applications? Something to report memory leaks, bad pointer operations etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: From the valgrind site, it seems that the only platform not supported is windows, since there is support for linux on various platform (x86, amd64, Darwin, S90 and ARM), Android and FreeBSD and NetBSD (experimental at this point)